# pentaho - extract and concatenate recurring nodes in xml with delimiter

Tags: xml, xpath, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to extract some data from xml using pentaho kettle.

I want to extract all the tr nodes in each table so that I can concatenate them with delimiter '/'

```
<entry>    
<table>
   <tr> item1 </tr>
   <tr> item2 </tr>
   <tr> item3 </tr>
   <tr> item4 </tr>
</table>   
</entry>
<entry>    
<table>
   <tr> item1 </tr>
   <tr> item2 </tr>
   <tr> item3 </tr>
   <tr> item4 </tr>
</table>   
</entry>
```

the result will be like

```
fieldname
item1/item2/item3/item4
item5/item6/item7/item8
```

is there a way to do this with XPath in Get data from XML

Right now Im using Get data from Xpath with this Loop Xpath

```
/*[name()='entry'][1]/*[name()='table']/*[name()='tr']
```

concatenate the result using javascript, put them in excel output and then repeat the steps til entry[20]. but later on I will have to increase the page query from 1 up to 20 so this method does not scale....

If anyone can help me out, I'd be grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

which version your are using for xpath 2.0 this will work

string-join(//table[1]/tr/text(),"/")

string-join(//table[2]/tr/text(),"/")

Comment: so should I set the loop xpath to be /*[name()='entry']

Comment: what output you are trying to get. i think previous given should be working. give the output you want

Comment: I get a xpath exception error saying no such function string-join

Comment: then your xpath version is 1.0

Comment: you have loop throgh each set and combine